# Как совместить создание RAID-массивов и таблицы разделов в секции %pre kickstart

Tags: centos, автоматизация

Пытаюсь автоматизировать создание логического диска на основе RAID-массива и подготовку таблицы разделов в секции %pre kickstart-файла. Т.е. в %pre у меня есть строки, отвечающие за создание логических дисков с помощью MegaCli (загружается MegaCli из-вне). С его помощью создается логический диск в RAID 1:

```
# Clear any existing configuration
./MegaCli64 -CfgClr -aALL
# Ensure the drives are in a good state before creating the logical device
./MegaCli64 -PDMakeGood -PhysDrv "[${e[0]}:${s[0]},${e[1]}:${s[1]}]" -Force -a0
# Create a RAID1 logical device from the detected disks
./MegaCli64 -CfgLdAdd -r1 "[${e[0]}:${s[0]},${e[1]}:${s[1]}]" -a0
```

Это работает. 
Далее я пытаюсь задать переменную, с помощью /dev/disk/by-path , чтобы впоследствии использовать не имя диска (например, /dev/sda), а UUID вида pci-0000:01:00.0-scsi-0:2:5:0:

```
     datadisk=$(ls -lh /dev/disk/by-path/ | grep 'scsi-0:2:0:0 ' | awk '{print $9}')
```

Проблема заключается в том, что в этот момент (%pre) отработки файла пока не содержится результата выдачи ls -lh /dev/disk/by-path/ | grep 'scsi-0:2:0:0 '. Я так понимаю из-за того, что udev пока еще не был запущен.

Можно все же как-то совместить эти две задачи в секции %pre kickstart-файла? Это требуется для максимально автоматизированного и универсального сценария установки ОС с помощью cobbler через PXE, т.к. серверы  имеем различных конфигураций и производителей.

Comment: можно ведь адресоваться и по *uuid*-у, который обычно получают из вывода программы `blkid`.